# Comparing datapoints expressed as proportions

Tags: proportion, biostatistics

My stats knowledge isn't very advanced, so it's been difficult to find any resources for the exact kind of comparison I want to do. As a summary:

I'm measuring insect development (i.e. how many bugs develop to adulthood from eggs). I have two groups (treatment and control) and within each group I have 5 replicates (separate containers). So the data I get from each experiment is a set of 5 control proportions and 5 treatment proportions.

Here is some sample data (number developing to adulthood/total number at start):

```
Control   Treatment
82/90     26/82
80/95     30/90
90/118    11/76
102/110   41/101
76/98     12/99
```

At first, a chi square test looked like the right way to go, but I'm unsure about lumping all my proportions together for such a test. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You should try logistic regression. Search this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a binomial generalised linear model, for which the data are perhaps more easily presented as something like

```
  +----------------------------+
  |     which   adults   total |
  |----------------------------|
  |   Control       82      90 |
  |   Control       80      95 |
  |   Control       90     118 |
  |   Control      102     110 |
  |   Control       76      98 |
  | Treatment       26      82 |
  | Treatment       30      90 |
  | Treatment       11      76 |
  | Treatment       41     101 |
  | Treatment       12      99 |
  +----------------------------+
```

In Stata, that could be `glm adults i.which, f(binomial total)` on the understanding that `which` has integer values underneath its text labels. The implied link is logit, so this could also be described as logistic regression. The logit model converges on the sample proportions of survival of about 0.842 and 0.268 for control and treatment, with suitably overwhelming figures of merit. I am confident that any decent statistical software should support this standard model, although that is a definition of *decent*.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your data. I do not disagree with the analysis suggested by @NickCox (+1). However,
before anything else I tried `prop.test` in R, to see if the five
control containers (and then, separately, the five treatment containers) gave
consistent proportions of adults per egg.

They do not:

```
bug.c = c(82,80,90,102,76)
egg.c = c(90,95,118,110,98)
prop.test(bug.c, egg.c)

         5-sample test for equality of proportions 
         without continuity correction

data:  bug.c out of egg.c
X-squared = 18.028, df = 4, p-value = 0.001219
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5 
0.9111111 0.8421053 0.7627119 0.9272727 0.7755102
```

It seems that container 3 had a lower proportion of adults/eggs
than average and that container 4 had a higher proportion.

In R, `prop.test` is just an alternative way to do a chi-squared
test on a contingency table for counts of adults and eggs that did
not produce adults.

```
TBL.c = rbind(bug.c, not.c)
TBL.c
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
bug.c   82   80   90  102   76
not.c    8   15   28    8   22

chisq.test(TBL.c)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL.c
X-squared = 18.028, df = 4, p-value = 0.001219
```

A look at the Pearson residuals (the squares of which are contributions
to the chi-squared statistic), shows absolute residuals above 2 for
containers 3 and 4.

```
chisq.test(TBL.c)$resid
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
bug.c  0.720038  0.00656621 -0.9328416  0.9808129 -0.7120038
not.c -1.659003 -0.01512887  2.1493129 -2.2598411  1.6404917
```

The same kind of analysis for the five *treatment* containers shows a similar
smaller proportion of adults/eggs for container 3 and larger for container 4.

It seems that there may be an interesting or important linkage between
'container numbers'--a sequence effect. Perhaps different temperatures at different times?

Overall, about 84% of control eggs yield adult bugs, and for treatment eggs the proportion is about 27%, clearly statistically significant. That difference may be the only important one for your work.
However, I mention the sequence effect because in analyzing somewhat similar
data some years ago, I found such a sequence effect and it turned out to
be an important one, leading to unexpected additional discoveries.